Проблемы с Github аккаунтом, 404
У меня есть (был) гитхаб аккаунт:

Спустя время я узнал от своего друга, что у меня проблемы с профилем — люди видят ошибку 404 на моей странице (UPD. При том что я не когда, не разу, не нарушал даже близко правила, что бы такое со мной случилось). Насколько мне известно, это называется теневым баном. Я дважды подал апелляцию, ждал почти месяц (было два тикета), но так и не получил ответа. Какую бы причину я ни указывал, никто даже не читает. В поддержке указано, что ответ должен прийти в течение одной рабочей недели, но прошло гораздо больше времени. Я не знаю, что делать. Профиль — мой личный, и он прокачан, я не могу его потерять. Помогите, пожалуйста.


Дубликаты: раз, два. Мы не техподдержка гитхаба и помочь с этим никак не можем

@andreymal

Я уже смотрел, и сделал все как она написала, не помогло мне не дают ответ
Это вообще про репо, а не про профиль, читайте что отправлять.

Я на то и пишу сюда, может есть почтовый адресс где они отвечают быстрей, или как то ускорить, или может статус посмотреть, я не знаю.

В общем, я ждал и потом увидел что значек Open крастный. Создал новый аккаунт и с него написал им. Там значек был зеленый. И они почти сразу ответили и разблокировали. Может кому пригодится.

а с чем это связано, удалось узнать?
